# Is there a Windows 10 equivalent of Apple Configurator for MacOS and iOS?

Tags: mac-osx, windows-10, ios

Apple Configurator at https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator is a tool that generates a mobileconfig file, which is an XML file that describes a specific configuration.

Install the mobileconfig XML file on a MacOS or iOS device, and the configuration is installed on that device.

Is there an equivalent of a mobileconfig file for Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Unattend.xml

The Windows Unattended Setup Reference provides a complete listing of all the settings that you can use to automate the configuration and the deployment of Windows 10.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/components-b-unattend